# How to package a react component on npm without store

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, npm-publish

I've been reading articles about how to publish react components to NPM, but I'm confused about the details when the component has a store implemented using a library like mobx.  Take a simple example like the component you can see in its entirety [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-cdn-ft9jf):

```js
const App = () => {
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    data: initialData,
    index: 0,
    addRow() {
      if (this.index < this.data.length) {
        this.data = [...this.data, addData[this.index++]];
      }
    }
  }));

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className="App">
      <MaterialTable
        columns={columns}
        data={store.data}
        title="Sample Material Table"
      />

      <Button onClick={store.addRow}>Add Row</Button>
    </div>
  ));
};
```

This example uses MobX, where `useObserver` and `useLocalStore` are specific to that library.  I personally am choosing to use MobX.  Let's say I publish this to NPM and use it in another project that prefers to use some other state management library.  I think what I have here is confusing in that scenario, and furthermore I'm not sure it would even work at all--or maybe it would...  I don't know.

The question is simple: how should I put this component together in such a way as to work with any state management library?

Comment: Use react `useState` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to use `mobx` and default `react hooks` as two different types of state management for your component.

Solution 1:

First, make `mobx` a peer dependency of your library, then structure your package 
in way that the end-user could use (import) your library like this:

```js
//for regular (default) usage with hooks
import myComponent from 'package-name/hooks'

// for mobx version
import myComponent from 'package-name/mobx'
```

In any case, you need to separate the usage of different state libraries, and internally try to reuse (share) as much code as possible when creating your library.

Solution 2:

Publish two (or maybe even three) different packages under the same [npm scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-an-org-scoped-package)
e.g `@myLib/mobx` and `@myLib/hooks` and possibly a third package that has the code
that is shared between all the packages `@myLib/default`